# x.Level Dynamic Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have data table designed as below for my project categories.

[image]

As you can see each category has its own ID and a Name and its parent's ID. the main Cats has 0 as their Parent ID.

And I have tried too many ways to render them on my page but no luck!

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <%
        DataSet Cats = new DataSet();
        DataSetTableAdapters.tblCategoryTableAdapter tblAdeptTblCategory = new DataSetTableAdapters.tblCategoryTableAdapter();
        tblAdeptTblCategory.FillBycParent(Cats.tblCategory, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < Cats.tblCategory.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            long ParentCatID = long.Parse(Cats.tblCategory.Rows[i]["cid"].ToString());
            Response.Write("<li class=\"list-group-item MainCat\">" + Cats.tblCategory.Rows[i]["cName"] + "<input type=\"button\" value =\"add\" class=\"btn pull-left btn-default btn-sm\" onclick=\"addpCats('AddCat', '" + Cats.tblCategory.Rows[i]["cid"] + "')\" />");
            DataSet SubCats = new DataSet();
            DataSetTableAdapters.tblCategoryTableAdapter tblAdptSubCatslist = new DataSetTableAdapters.tblCategoryTableAdapter();
            tblAdptSubCatslist.FillBycParent(SubCats.tblCategory, ParentCatID);
            Response.Write("<ul id=\"SubCat\" class=\"list-group SubCat\">");
            for (int j = 0; j < SubCats.tblCategory.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                Response.Write("<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + SubCats.tblCategory.Rows[j]["cName"] + "<input type=\"button\" value =\"اعمال\" class=\"btn pull-left btn-default btn-sm\" onclick=\"addpCats('AddCat', '" + SubCats.tblCategory.Rows[j]["cid"] + "')\" /></li>");
            }

            Response.Write("</ul>");
            Response.Write("</li>"); 
        }
    %>
</ul>
```

As you can see it is only for 2 levels or more if we know the level depth in advance and for more levels it needs too much coding.

Comment: http://www.niteshluharuka.com/how-to-create-multi-level-menu-dynamically-using-c-in-asp-net/

Comment: You should follow a recursive logic here.

Comment: Yeah Dear @TolgaEvcimen u r right! I tried that but it got too complicated and thrown stack over flow.

Comment: I would recommend you to implement the recursive logic on your serverside code, then you can use the formed html in your view. Client side is not for real logic operations. Always keep the client side the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .net menu control for that for more example please refer following link
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526004/Database-Driven-Dynamic-Menu-Control